# Error when attempted to install ubuntu(or any linux distro)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb, intel

I have the following hardware:
Motherboard - Gigabyte B760 Gaming X
Processor - Intel Core i5 12400
GPU - Gigabyte GeForce RTX 4060 ti

When trying to install Ubuntu from usb stick I first thing see the messages:

```
[1.634175] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller
[1.634182] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Notification initialization failed (-1)
[4.427488] nouneau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (196000a1) 
_
```

and it just hangs here.
This happens with Linux Manjaro, Mint, Kubuntu, Ubuntu

Comment: Your details are vague & don't rule out user-procedural errors. You mention various OSes (including off-topic) but without any release details (inc. kernel stack details as Ubuntu LTS releases have choices selected by ISO download) so how are we to know? Did you verify ISO? validate ISO write to media?  Choose appropriate releases for your hardware?  Your lack of specific details implies possible user procedural issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: turned out that there was an issue with video card @guiverc